# Convert YYYY-mm-dd to day of the week format in R

Tags: r

How to convert this date format `2017-11-01`  into name of day of the week i.e.`Wednesday`, using R?

Comment: `weekdays(as.Date('2017-11-01'))`

Answer (score 4):

```
> format(as.Date('2017-11-01'), '%A')
[1] "Wednesday"
```

Comment: how do it my dataset?   dataset$month  format(as.Date('dataset$month'), '%A') right?

Comment: you have to specify the format of your column, if it's `Date` then you just do `my_data$my_new_column <- format(my_data$my_column, '%A')`